# what is meant by left most derivation?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, compiler-construction

Please help me understand what is meant by `Left Most Derivation` the second `L` in `LL Parser`.

Explain it with a simplest example.

I saw the following picture explaining *Left most derivation* but I do not understand it :

[image]

Comment: I think left most derivation means you always apply a rule # to the leftmost place you can apply it. So I can just say 'Rule N -> N D' and you know to apply it in the leftmost place you can. If it was an RR Parser it'd apply it on the rightmost place it could.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The grammar rules are displayed on the left with Nonterminal symbols and terminal symbols. Nonterminal symbols should be Capital letters, everything else is typically a terminal symbol. In the example N and D are nonterminal and 0-9 are terminals. A Left Most Derivation ALWAYS makes the left most nonterminal go through a grammar rule. Trying to format the example below.

```
N
=> N D   --Replaces the first/left most/only (which is "N") with the N => N D rule
=> N D D --Replaces the first/left most nonterminal (which is "N") with the N => N D rule
=> D D D --Replaces the first nonterminal (which is "N") with the N => D rule
=> 1 D D --Replaces the first nonterminal ("D") with the D => 1 rule(our first terminal character!)
=> 1 2 D --Replaces the first nonterminal ("D") with the D => 2 rule
=> 1 2 3 --Replaces the first nonterminal ("D") with the D => 3 rule
-- Only terminal characters remain, derivation/reduction is complete.
```